# Building log4cxx with unixodbc

Tags: c++, centos, unixodbc, log4cxx

I have been trying to build log4cxx with unixodbc (I can connect to the database using console), but when trying to build log4cxx --with-ODBC, the ./configure always results in configure: error: unixODBC not found !

I have tried setting my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to where unixODBC is. Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it with unixODBC 2.3.2 and it seems fine, can you post the output from confure where it fails to find unixODBC.